# Printing numbers that exclude those that end with x

Tags: java

I want to print the numbers from 0-100, excluding those that are multiples of 7 and those that end with 7. I can do all except the ending with 7 part. Is there a charAt equivalent for int?

Done, thanks for the help!

```
class revision{

  public static void main(String[] args){

    for(int i = 0; i < 101; i++){
      if(i % 7 != 0 && i % 10 != 7){

      System.out.println(i);

      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: **for(int i = 0; i < 101; i++){
          if(i % 7 != 0&&i%10!=7){
 
          System.out.println(i);

          }
        }**

Comment: if (i.toString.substr(-1) != '7') {}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a charAt equivalent for int?

Sort of: There's the remainder operation you're already using, just with a different divisor:  `i % 10 != 7` will weed out numbers "ending with 7." *(In decimal; if you wanted to do it in octal, it would be `% 8`; or in hex it would be `% 16`, etc. E.g., you're isolating the "ones" digit by doing a remainder with the number base.)*

So:

```
class revision{

  public static void main(String[] args){

    for(int i = 0; i < 101; i++){
      if(i % 7 != 0 && i % 10 != 7){
    // ------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

      System.out.println(i);

      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

Side note: In Java, the overwhelming convention is for class names to start with an upper-case character. So `Revision` rather than `revision`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a `charAt` to achieve what you want:

```
public static boolean string7(int input) {
    String inputString = input + "";
    return (input / 7 == 0) || (Character.getNumericValue(input.charAt(input.length() - 1)));
}
```

The other answers did not answer the concrete question because the method above is not optimal at all and the authors intended to show a better way. I agree with them because this method involves conversion to `String`, which is a very costly operation. You will not feel it in a single call, but if it is called in a multidimensional cycle, then a performance drop should be felt. So, in agreement with previous answers, a better way to achieve the result you want would be like this:

```
public static boolean int7(int input) {
    return (input / 7 == 0) || (input % 7 == 0);
}
```

You might have very large numbers as `input` in the future. To cope with that situation, you will have to work with [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).